# AJAX request sends empty form data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the code which sends data to the database. It works correctly when I filled form field and click the 'Add Record' button. It inserts the data successfully in the database.

However the main problem is that if the form field is empty and then I click the button, it sends empty data to the database.

```js
function addRecord() {
  var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]); //It automatically collects all fields from form
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php",
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(output) {
      alertify.set('notifier', 'delay', 3);
      alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
      alertify.success('Data Inserted Successfully');
      readRecords();
      $('#form1').trigger("reset");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: In `ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php`, do a `print_r($_POST);` and post the output here.

Comment: `if the form field is empty and then I click the button, it sends empty data to the database` This is standard behaviour. Is your problem that you want to validate all fields are completed before allowing the form to be submit? Also, *remove `async: false`*. It's terrible practice and there's no need for it here as you're using the callback pattern properly.

Comment: add `required` attribute in input tag like `<input type="text" name="first_name" required >`. also you can used javascript & jquery for validate before ajax request send

Comment: you have to check if data is empty in your php file.

Comment: because you are not handle and validate for blank values

Comment: validate your inputs either in  bakcend or frontend.

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 places where you can tackle empty data issue before saving to database

1- Put required attribute in your input elements so that user can not submit empty fields.

2- validate your form data in java-script function addRecord() before making ajax request. if the validation is complete send ajax call else show message to user to fill the data.

3- validate your data that you received in $_POST variable and if fields are empty, send error message back in ajax response and show error to user.

Comment: How can I validate it?

Comment: put required in form input tags like this <input type="text" name="fieldname" required >

Answer (score 0):

When You get form data value while you should the form field value is empty or not... or use print_r($_POST) data..

/* on submitting my form */

```
  $( '#myform' ).submit(function() {

               var errors = [];

        /*     else if Textarea is empty display message error */
               if($('#myform textarea').val()=="") {  
                    errors[errors.length] = 'enter your message';
                }

        /*      if radio button is not being selected display message error */
                if (!$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
                   errors[errors.length] = 'select a radio';
                }

                if(errors.length > 0){
                    var errMsg = "Please "

                    for(e = 0; e < errors.length-1; e++){
                        errMsg += errors[e]+", ";
                    }

                     errMsg = errMsg.substr(0, errMsg.length -2)+" and "+errors[errors.length-1];
                     $('#errors').empty().text(errMsg);
                     return false;
                }

        /*          Everthing is good display success message and add SENDING class to submit button */
                    else {
                        $('#myform :submit').addClass('sending').html('Sending message...');
                        $('#errors').empty().text('All Good :D');
                    }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to set the contentType property to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in order to parse this in the backend server.